# Dispatch custom event for all methods that extends a parent method

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I'm developing a module that will be extended by other modules. Here I will call the parent module as `parent` and the "child" module (the module that will extend the classes from `parent`) as `child`.

I have an abstract class declared for the `parent` that has an abstract method called `loadExternalItem`. This method loads an external item (like a product) from an external source. For the `child` module in this case, that external source is an ERP API that is called in this method to retrieve a product:

```php
<?php

class Child_Module_Model_Entity_Product extends Parent_Module_Model_Entity_Abstract
{
    /** Inherited from Parent_Module_Model_Entity_Abstract */
    public function loadExternalItem($item)
    {
        $query = array("query_parameters" => array("id" => $item->getId()));
        $response = Mage::getModel("child/api_request")
            ->make("GET", "PRODUCT_BY_ID", $query);

        return $response->getItemFromResponse();
    }
}
```

My question is: where (**in the `parent` module**) shoud I dispatch my event (say `my_custom_event`) in a way that all modules that extends `loadExternalItem` run it without specifying it in the inherited method's body?

Anyway to do that with `abstract methods`? Only way I can think is to not declare the method as abstract and call the dispatch event in the body of the `parent` method:

```php
<?php

class Parent_Module_Model_Entity_Abstract extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function loadExternalItem($item)
    {
        Mage::dispatchEvent("my_custom_event");
    }
}
```

And call it at the end of the `child`'s method:

```php
<?php

class Child_Module_Model_Entity_Product extends Parent_Module_Model_Entity_Abstract
{
    /** Inherited from Parent_Module_Model_Entity_Abstract */
    public function loadExternalItem($item)
    {
        $query = array("query_parameters" => array("id" => $item->getId()));
        $response = Mage::getModel("child/api_request")
            ->make("GET", "PRODUCT_BY_ID", $query);

        $responseItem = $response->getItemFromResponse();
        parent::importExternalItem($item); /** Calls the dispatch event */
        return $responseItem;
    }
}
```

But it seems "hacky" and not so efficient, because the main reason is to avoid that developers working in a new child module forget to dispatch this event, and in this case they might as well forget to call the `parent::importExternalItem()`.